# How do I declare an image in a static context in Android?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I was wondering if it is possible to reference an image in a static variable? I'm trying to modify a shopping cart example which I have, but I'm having trouble adding an image to the existing list of items. I'm not sure if i'm asking the question correctly, however, it may be better if I try with examples, so here goes...

I have an ImageView declared as follows:

```
public static ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivProductImage);
```

I then placed an image onto the imageview as follows:

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

The reason why I need to have it static is because I require it to be called in a static variable as follows:

```
public static final Product PRODUCT1 = new Product(1, imgView, "Product Name", BigDecimal.valueOf(4.00), "Product Description");
```

I really just want to add an image for each product variable. So is there an easier method where I can just place an image, where I have `imgView` in the static `Product` variable?

I am not sure if there is a more efficient method than what I stated above, however, I'm hoping that you guys can shine some light on this :) Thank you everyone for reading, and I look forward to your assistance and guidance.

Answer (score 3):

> I have an ImageView declared as follows:

That has two problems:

1. It will either crash (most likely) or possibly return `null`.
2. It will leak memory.

You cannot call `findViewById()` until after `setContentView()` has been called (or the view that you are looking to find otherwise has been created). That cannot be done from static initializers. Typically, it is done in `onCreate()` of the activity.

Holding onto an `ImageView` in a `static` field in turn holds onto the entire `Activity` and everything else the `Activity` references. Moreover, once the user rotates the screen, resizes their window, or otherwise causes a configuration change, your `ImageView` will no longer be valid. A new `Activity` instance will be created, but your `static` `ImageView` will be for the old `Activity`.

> The reason why I need to have it static is because I require it to be called in a static variable as follows:

Get rid of that `static` field and solve your problem in some other way.

Comment: Okay, well...what I really want to achieve is to just place an image, where my imgview is required in the static variable. Is that possible? For example,

public static final Product PRODUCT1 = new Product(1, R.drawable.bg, "Product Name", BigDecimal.valueOf(4.00), "Product Description");

Comment: @PaulSamaroo: "where my imgview is required in the static variable" -- I guarantee you that it is not required to be `static`. You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you ask how best to solve whatever your real problem is.